# Cannot type in input field when using value={}

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS, and trying to build a form to update a supplier.

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text"
       ref={nameDisplayedRef}
       className='p-2 rounded'
       name='nameDisplayed'
       defaultValue={supplier.nameDisplayed}
       value={supplier.nameDisplayed}
/>
```

When the input is like this, I cannot type in to it.  I have read that I need an `onChange` function - but I dont *need* an onChange function.  I dont care when its changed, I care when the form is submitted.

The data provided to this input field comes from an API call made by useSWR.  When I update the database, the field only updates if I have the `value={}` in the input field.  But with it I cannot change the input text.

I appreciate that i need an onChange function but what am I supposed to put in it? It wont let me leave it empty so I am not sure what to do.

edit:
Adding `nameDisplayedRef.current.value = supplier.nameDisplayed` solves the problem but typescript shows an error for it in PhpStorm.  But the code works at least :\

Comment: *"but I dont need an onChange function. I dont care when its changed"* - But the exact question you're asking is that it's not updating the display when the value is changed.  It sounds like you **do care** when it's changed, and want that change to be reflected in the component's rendering.

Comment: @David thanks for responding.  I meant that useSWR is handling the change for me, so I am not sure what I would need to write in the onChange function since the value is updated automatically.#

Comment: Given the code shown, presumably the `onChange` handler would update the state value in `supplier.nameDisplayed`, no?

Comment: @David but there is no state value to set.  The `supplier` object is handled by `useSWR` which magically handles the object for me.  Its not in the state

Comment: Then it's not clear to me what behavior you're expecting.  If `supplier.nameDisplayed` isn't a value you want to control or update, and it's the value you want this `<input>` to contain, and it's the value you want the submitted form to use, then what exactly is the purpose of being able to modify it in the UI?  You either want to change the value in the `<input>` or you don't, you can't have it both ways.

Comment: @David I think you might be right.  Using defaultValue might be enough, as actually it would be very frustrating to be typing into a form and suddenly the value updates if someone modifies the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is controlled vs uncontrolled inputs.

An uncontrolled input is when an input handles value and change on its own.

A controlled input is when you control the input externally. What you want to do is use some kind of state to manage the value of the component (which handles the initial value) and the onChange handler will set the state that is placed in the value.

Here's an example with useState:

```
const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(initialVal)

<input
  type="text"
  value={stateValue}
  onChange={(e)=>setState(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: Edited to add a snippet